# Функция удаления последнего элемента pop в стеке

Tags: c, list, стек

Доброго времени суток! 
Такой вопрос. Есть стек, заданный списком.

```
struct Stack 
    {
        int data;
        struct Stack* next;
    };
```

Как реализовать функцию удаления последнего элемента в списке `pop`? У нее, как я понял, должен быть такой прототип `void pop(Stack** head)`, так как в C нельзя передавать ссылки в функцию. Пытался написать сам, но запутался в указателях, я в них не силен.

Comment: Вообще-то, стек - это структура данных, из которой элементы удаляются из начала стека. То есть вы должны удалять не последний элемент списка, а первый.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow это же очередь а не стек, со стека как раз с конца удаляются ведь

Comment: @ampawd Почему очередь названа Stack?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow очередь не названа стеком )) очередь это другая структура данных, автор вопроса хочет именно стек и функцию `pop` которая бы удаляла элемент с вершины стека (тоесть с конца) а причём тут очередь и удаления из начала вобще не ясно

Comment: @ampawd Вершина стека - это начало односвязного списка. В начало списка добавляются элементы, и из начала списка удаляются элементы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите организовать стек на основе односвязного списка, то не имеет никакого смысла добавлять элементы в конец списка, и удалять их с конца списка, так как такой код крайне не эффективный.

Поэтому лучше определить функции `push` и `pop` следующим образом, как это показано в демонстрационной программе ниже, добавляя и извлекая данные из начала списка.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Stack 
{
    int data;
    struct Stack* next;
};

int push( struct Stack **stack, int data )
{
    struct Stack *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct Stack ) );
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->next = *stack;
        *stack = tmp;
    }

    return success;
}

void pop( struct Stack **stack )
{
    if ( *stack )
    {
        struct Stack *tmp = *stack;
        *stack = ( *stack )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}

int empty( struct Stack **stack )
{
    return *stack == NULL;
}

int top( struct Stack **stack )
{
    return ( *stack )->data;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;
    struct Stack *stack = NULL;

    int i = 0;
    while ( i < N && push( &stack, i ) ) i++;

    while ( !empty( &stack ) )
    {
        printf( "%d ", top( &stack ) );
        pop( &stack );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

То есть число 9 было последним занесено в стек и первым вытолкнуто из стека.

Comment: абсолютно спокойно можно добавлять и удалять элементы с конца и при этом иметь константую сложность для обоих этих операций - например, если иметь указатель как на головной так и на хвостовой элемент списка

Comment: @ampawd Во-первых, имеется в виду односторонний список, так как иначе придется в функции передавать еще один указатель на конец списка, либо вводить дополнительную структуру, служащую оберткой данной структуры. Но даже в этом случае у вас не будет константной сложности удаления элемента, так как вам надо будет вычислить предыдущий перед хвостовым элемент. То есть для удаления элемента с конца списка хвостовой элемент никак не помогает.

Comment: тогда при добавлении, можно хранить указатель на элемент стоящий перед хвостовым, чтобы его каждый раз не вычислять перед удалением.

Comment: @ampawd Это также не помогает, так как после удаления элемента, вам снова нужно вычислять, какой элемент является предпоследним.

Comment: ок, но если список двухсвязный то спокойно можно иметь константную сложность

Comment: Возможно `int pop(struct Stack **stack, int *pdata);` пользоваться более удобно

Comment: @avp Да, такой подход также заслуживает быть используемым.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
void pop(struct Stack** head)
{
    if (*head == NULL) return; // Пустой стек

    if ((*head)->next == NULL)    // Единственный элемент
    {
        free(*head);
        *head = NULL;
        return;
    }
    struct Stack* header = head;
    while(header->next->next)
    {
        header = header->next;
    }
    free(header->next);
    header->next = NULL;
}
```